# Find the area included between an arc of cycloid $x=a(\theta - \sin (\theta))$, $y=a(1-\cos (\theta))$ and its base.

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Find the area included between an arc of cycloid $x=a(\theta - \sin (\theta))$, $y=a(1-\cos (\theta))$ and its base.

My Attempt:

The graph of the cycloid looks like:
[image]

So the area of the loop is
$$Area=2\int_{0}^{a\pi} y dx$$

My book however says that the limit of integration is from $0$ to $\pi$. I couldn't understand how is that possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to use integration to compute an area.

What you seem to have overlooked is that you are given a parametric equation for the cycloid, namely

$$\begin{align*}
x(\theta) &= a (\theta - \sin \theta) \\
y(\theta) &= a (1 - \cos \theta)
\end{align*}$$

which, for a fixed constant $a$, relates the $(x,y)$ coordinate of a point on the cycloid to a *parameter* $\theta$.  Therefore, the expression for the area $$\int y \, dx$$ that you cite is not an integral with respect to $x$, but actually with respect to $\theta$.  Written out completely, it actually means

$$A = \int_{\theta = \theta_0}^{\theta_1} y(\theta) \, \frac{d}{d\theta}[x(\theta)] \, d\theta.$$

In your case the interval of integration over half a period is $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ as the text states.